# Define transparent color in singleband pseudocolor raster layer style

Tags: qgis, raster, style

Can I somehow define "transparent" color for values higher than 32000 in raster layer? See the style dialog:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can. Double click on that colour icon and set its alpha value

[image]

If you would like gradually change it over a range, or fade it in and out, you can use the new alpha colour ramp support

[image]

See [Alpha in QGIS colour ramps. Oh yeah!](http://nathanw.net/2013/05/21/alpha-in-qgis-colour-ramps-oh-yeah/) for a example.  It's simply a matter of defining a new colour ramp but setting which values you want transparent

Comment: Thanks Nathan! But I am lost in alpha channels, I tried to use them once in GIMP but never understood them, sorry... can you please give me example how to set 100% transparent (invisible) color?

Comment: You just have to set the alpha value to 0

Comment: Nathan, I don't have the "alpha channel" field in the dialogue!

Comment: You might need to update your qgis dev version.

Comment: Nathan, really? I have version 1.9.0-Master, which is quite new - newer than is [the one provided normally for new users](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#11-Standalone-Installer-recommended-for-new-users). What is qgis dev and where can I find its version? I don't see it in `Help > About`.

Comment: Yes it's 1.9, but you you might not have the version with the alpha changes.

Comment: Nathan, is this feature quite recent (last 1-2 month?)

Comment: Nathan, I prefer comments over chat, they will stay logged here.

Comment: If you double click on one of the colours you don't see the alpha bit?

Comment: Nathan, nope. Maybe it is a development version problem only.

Answer (score 2):

This is just an update to QGIS 2.18 to the previous answer.

The current set color tab does not have alpha any longer, now it is under Opacity. Once it is set to 0% produce the full transparency.

[image]